# What pycharm's config files are worthy of being in the repository

Tags: git, ide, pycharm

Me and my colleagues are working on a project in pycharm.
Usually it is not a good idea to have any of the files in the `.idea` folder in the repository itself, since they are user and computer specific.
However some files might be useful. For example i found the under `.idea/inspectionProfiles/` `Project_Default.xml` where the Naming inspection of PEP8 is modified. This would be very useful to have in repository, so the coding convention is automatically used.

Is there a list, or at least some recommendation which general configuration files should be held in the repository???

Comment: You may want to start here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems